# Trying to figure out what this ornamental period font is

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have these two fonts and I would like help identifying each one please.

1st font

[image]

2nd font

[image]

Comment: Looks like **ACCEPT** is a different font than **RSVP**. At least the `P`s are different.

Comment: @ckpepper02 that was my initial assumption as well, but they are identical except for the curl: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7LdX5.png. So they're from the same family, or one is a modified version, or maybe one is upper-case and the other is lower-case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found by doing a (long and manual) search for Halloween fonts! Both your examples are the same one, just upper and lowecase.

The font is called [Antique Shop Regular](http://www.letterheadfonts.com/fonts/antiqueshop.php).

> Antique shop has a unique period style. Features ornamental caps,
>   automatic ligatures and manual stylistic alternates.

[image]